# Reflection Principle

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$U^+ \colon= \left\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n\mid |x| < 1, x_n>0\right\}$ is an open half-ball. Assume $u \in C^2 (\overline{U^+}$) is harmonic in $U^+$ with $u=0$ on $\partial U^+ \cap  \{x_n=0\}$.

Set $v(x)=u(x)$ if $x_n \geq 0$ and $v(x)=u(x_1,x_2,..., -x_n)$ if $x_n < 0$ for $x \in U=B^0(0,1)$ . Prove $v \in C^2$ ($U$), and thus $v$ is harmonic within $U$.

Comment: I'm not sure if $v$ is well defined this way. What about $x\in U$ with $x_n<0$?

Comment: v is now well defined.

Comment: What have you tried? It seems like you just need to fight with a few derivatives and make some arguments about why it's okay to take a limit or two.

Comment: Expressing that the limits from the positive and the negative sides, approaching the line between the half balls, are equal to each other is troublesome.

Comment: @Seeker: I believe you need to define $v(x)=\mathbf{-} u(x_1,x_2,...,\mathbf{-}x_n)$ in the other half of the ball (odd extension). Even extension (the one you describe above) is used when $\partial_{\hat{n}} u = 0$ on the boundary.

Comment: I don't believe there may be a need to worry about odd/even extension as such. A solution has been presented in terms of showing the first partial derivatives of u and the v w.r.t. all xi, i=1, 2,..., n-1 exist, are continuous and then argue the same for the last x (i.e., xn) separately by the difference quotient. Then discuss the second partials of u and v similarly to finally show that from u being harmonic, it follows that the Laplacian of v is also zero implying that v is harmonic as well.